# Easiest way to migrate C scripts to a GoDaddy hosted account

Tags: c

Almost 20 years ago I built a somewhat dynamic (for the time) web site using C code to generate the html. Over the next 5 or so years I added a lot of functionality.

Now I'm trying to move the site. I don't want to take down the pages, but I don't want to continue paying nearly $1k a year to keep the site up. At this point I very rarely actually update the content.

So I'm trying to move the site to a GoDaddy. Currently I'm planning on using their Delux Linux hosting package. At

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to use C serverside scripts with goDaddy? If I go with a Windows hosting plan could I compile the C and just upload the executables? Use the ASP.Net framework? Or can you suggest a hosting company that will let me compile C programs to use?

To be clear - I know I'm not going to be able to drop my C programs in place and have them work. I just want to limit the amount of time I'm going to have to spend to get the site up and running on a new provider

Not that it's relevant to the question, but my site is http://www.onhiatus.com

Thanks, Tony

Comment: You haven't specified the operating system the original code runs on, or what sort of privileges it requires to run, etc.

Comment: That's the issue. Most providers (including goDaddy) won't give you shell access with gcc. So I was looking for a method to compile off system and upload the resulting binaries. I ended up going with a different provider that was willing to give me shell and gcc access making the port just a matter of adjusting paths. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just take the c programs you have, assuming they will run under the linux hosted account (or maybe windows if you are using any asp.net features), and then do a **bin deploy** of them to the godaddy hosted filesystem. Basically, you make them into .dll's and upload them into /bin, and include all the other .html or whatever extensions you are using in there as well. Include the scripts, the images, and the css files. You should be good to go.

From looking at your site it seems you are running Apache 1.3 and PHP 4.0. I believe this setup will be easily supported by godaddy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The problem was how to compile them since GoDaddy wouldn't give me shell access (at least not with gcc enabled). I ended up going with HawkHost since they were A) cheap; and B) willing to give me the tools needed (shell w/ gcc access)